# Spotify crashing on everything but radio

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, crash, spotify

I have a Spotify Unlimited account and I am trying to use the native Linux version of the application (v0.4.9.302.g604b4fb3). When I play radio, everything is fine. Also, when I have my Play Queue filled up by the Radio playing and I change tracks, it works fine.

However, when I try to search for a song and then play it - it crashes. Also, when I find a song and then add it to the play queue (alongside the radio tracks) it also crashed when it reaches that song.

When I run it from terminal and crash it, this is the output:

```
21:50:53.662 I [ap:1387] Connecting to AP B3.spotify.com:4070
21:50:53.697 I [upnp:515] 192.168.1.254: got external ip 0x0
21:50:53.698 I [ap:937] Connected to AP: 78.31.8.43:4070
21:50:53.725 I [upnp:463] 192.168.1.254: mapping add ok
21:50:53.738 I [upnp:489] 192.168.1.254: Port 27538 mapped OK
connecting notifications
connecting notifications
connecting notifications
21:50:53.922 I [gui-model:2136] Login Code: 0
connecting notifications
21:50:54.485 I [upnp:515] 192.168.1.1: got external ip 0x3EA3B350
21:50:54.517 I [upnp:463] 192.168.1.1: mapping add ok
21:50:54.519 I [upnp:489] 192.168.1.1: Port 27538 mapped OK
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is not Gtk2 (0).
[000:000] Using Xt toolkit
** (<unknown>:4234): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (<unknown>:4234): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
** (<unknown>:4234): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (<unknown>:4234): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
** (<unknown>:4234): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (<unknown>:4234): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
** (<unknown>:4234): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (<unknown>:4234): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.7) (6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

(<unknown>:4234): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_origin: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(<unknown>:4234): Gdk-WARNING **: /build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.20.1/gdk/x11/gdkdrawable-x11.c:952 drawable is not a pixmap or window

(<unknown>:4234): Gdk-WARNING **: GdkWindow 0x3a0007f unexpectedly destroyed

(<unknown>:4234): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_origin: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(<unknown>:4234): Gdk-WARNING **: /build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.20.1/gdk/x11/gdkdrawable-x11.c:952 drawable is not a pixmap or window

(<unknown>:4234): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_origin: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(<unknown>:4234): Gdk-WARNING **: /build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.20.1/gdk/x11/gdkdrawable-x11.c:952 drawable is not a pixmap or window

(<unknown>:4234): Gdk-WARNING **: GdkWindow 0x3a00082 unexpectedly destroyed
21:50:59.219 I [main.cpp:603] Using PulseAudio
[mp3 @ 0x329e410]mdb:45, lastbuf:0 skipping granule 0
Segmentation fault
```

I last used this version of the application a few months ago (max 2) and it worked properly. I am running Ubuntu 10.04 with all updates installed to date. Has anyone had a similar issue?

EDIT: When I load an album from the main page (one of the "Latest" albums) it seems to play ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If upgrade a possibility, Spotify is currently up to version 0.6.2.301.

You could also try uninstall and reinstall of Spotify from scratch.

The problem can also be a conflict with another running application, so try to close as many as possible.